# Is it possible to load multiple videos into HTML 5 video player and have them play in a sequence, one after the other?

Tags: html, video

i need help with loading multiple videos into HTML 5 web page so that the player can play them in a sequence, is there any way to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var media = [ 
"http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4",
 "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerJoyrides.mp4",
 "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4",
"http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4",];
 var vIndex = 0;
 
 function nextVideo() {
  vIndex = (vIndex+1)%media.length;
  video.src = media[vIndex];
  video.currentTime = 0;
  video.play();
 }
```

```html
<video id="video" width="400" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4" onended="nextVideo()" controls></video>
```

Comment: Thanks really appreciate this a lot

Comment: Always welcome ) if it's sutisfied you, please accept the answer

Comment: Hey Yosef, How might I do this seamlessly so that they buffer/preload in the same way they would if a single video?